# cancel git add -A

Tags: git, git-add

By mistake I run the command

```
git add -A
```

and then (when I figured out) I stopped it using

```
Ctrl+C
```

Is there a way to reset the repository to the point before the `git add -A`?

`git status` shows:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    1xx_xx/xx.m~
#   modified:   2xx_xx/xx_xx.m
#   deleted:    3xx_xx/xx_xx.m~
#   modified:   4xx_xx/xx_xx.m
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   xx_xxvariables_ldac/
#   xx_xx/variables_ldac_template/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: what does git status show now?

Comment: git reset --mixed  More info http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: git status is very very slow...it doesnt show anything yet

Comment: I edited the question with the output of git status...
xx_xx is for privacy

Comment: Well it looks like nothing is in index. So you are already where you want to be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `git reset --mixed` will reset the index which sounds like your goal.

> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.